# Delete relationship between entities in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

For example, I have such simple model:

```
var address = _dbContext.Addresses.Add(new Address()
{
    AddressId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    StreetName = "Test street name"
}).Entity;
_dbContext.Libraries.Add(new Library()
{
    LibraryId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    Name = "Test library",
    Address = address
});
```

However, how can I break relationship between them? If I simply want to keep test library and test address in database, but break relationship between them, foreign key of the test library must be null, I suppose. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

your entity-model has to be nullable on the foreign-key column.

```
public class Library
{
    ...
    public Guid? AddressId{get;set;}
    public virtual Address Address {get;set;}
}
```

then you can set Adress to null. otherwise it's not possible I think

Comment: I'm not setting AddressId _null_ explicitly, I set navigation property `Address` to null, which is obviously nullable.

Comment: this won't work since entity-framework gets the referenced object with the primary key from your GUID-column like a join-statement.

Comment: The Address is only virtual and NOT saved in your database. The AddressId-column IS saved.
If you only want to get null if you ask for the relation, just write something like this (i know it's not completely correct syntax)
`public virtual Adress Adress {get {return null;};set{Adress =value}}`

Comment: This is EF Core, we don't need _virtual_ keyword either, _virtual_ used to lazy loading. However, breaking the model, not the best option, it's better to avoid such intervention.

Comment: i know this is about ef core, but that we don't need `virtual` i didn't knew :D good to know, thanks for this.

Comment: mhh.. why do you really want to do this? what's your target?

Comment: I need to know, how can I break only relationships in EF core, without deleting connected objects. I need to know about such thing, because in my application I have choice, where you can choose, for example, address for library, but if you didn't choose any address, it doesn't mean that this address doesn't exist and need to be destroyed. Many words, but I really need this feature.